# Check if array contains certain string, then select that item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, src

Okay, this might sound very vague, but I will try to explain best I can.

I have an image, and I collected its source with the `.attr('src')` function. This image is one of 5 other images, all in the same div. So far I have collected two things:

1. var src, which contains the url of the image I clicked.
2. var array, an array which contains all of the images in the div.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="images">
 <img src="path1" />
 <img src="path2" />
 <img src="path3" />
 <img src="path4" />
 <img src="path5" />
</div>
```

Imagine, I clicked the third image. The variable 'src' will contain the value 'path3'. I want, when I click on an arrow icon I have at the bottom of my page, that the value will be switched to 'path2', the previous item in the array.

How do I do this?

Comment: Selected Image src will be switched with previous one when arrow icon is clicked? Can you please edit your question and give us idea about your expected output.

Comment: Use the jquery `prev` function, like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/krxx7v7d/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your variables `src` and `array`:

```
var index = array.findIndex(function(img) {
    return img.src === src
})

var elementYouWant = array[index - 1]
```

You may add a check if `index` is zero, because in that case `index - 1` would be `-1` and `elementYouWant` will be `undefined`. Same for `array.length`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your images are placed in the same parent `<div>` element, you can use jQuery's [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to access the immediate previous sibling of a specified element:

```
function getPrevSrc (currentSrc) {
    // Get DOM element with the given src attribute
    // could be optimized by providing a parent element
    var $currentImg = $("[src='" + currentSrc + "']");

    // Get previous sibling
    // Note that using this on the first image is an edge case,
    // so you have to handle it accordingly to your needs
    var $prevImg = $currentImg.prev();

    // Return previous src
    return $prevImg.attr("src");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageArray; //Ur images array;
var index=imageArray.indexOf(src);
if(index>0) {
  src=imageArray[index-1]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try below code :

```
$('img').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('src'));
    alert($(this).prev('img').attr('data-value'));
});
```

You can check here : https://jsfiddle.net/xeq4yn0z/